# phpstorm: launch a command on commit and update

Tags: ssh, command, phpstorm

Is it possible to launch a .sh script (using "Remove SSH External Tools) automatically when I (SVN) update or commit ?

I see no options and informations about this on the PhpStorm docs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an phpstorm option, but you can do that with svn. You need to register a hook for update and commit pointing to your script. This [page](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7151/) should help you with creating such hook scripts. PHPStorm will trigger them as expected, because it also just uses the command line for you.

Comment: I'm not able to use svn hook because it's on a different vms used by each developers. So it has to come from PhpStorm and not from SVN.

Comment: You are thinking server side hooks, that you can't do. But you can create local hooks, too, which is what you need here.